# Why for loop not processing the entire input string?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I'm new to Python coding. I am enrolled in the online course DEV274X: Introduction to Python fundamentals provided by Microsoft.

For my first assignment, I had to write a code that processes a given string and prints the words whose first letter are greater than or equal to 'h' in a new line

**Only using the following methods:** for/in (iteration), input, if, else, .isalpha() method, .lower() or .upper() method. The string was "Wheresoever you go, go with all your heart" and the desired output was 
[image]

My code and the output I got was

[image]

Can someone help me by telling me what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us, inline in the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is correct just a small mistake.
The last line is

```
print(ltr)
```

which will print only 't', the last iterated letter. You have to change it to 'new' and check if it is >'h'

```
quote="Wheresoever you go, go with all your heart"
new= ''
for letter in quote:
    if letter.isalpha():
        new+= letter
    elif new.lower() >= 'h':
        print(new.upper())
        new= ''
    else:
        new= ''
if new.lower() >= 'h':
     print(new.upper())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
quote="wheresoever you go,go with your heart"
newword=""
for letter in quote:
    if letter.isalpha():
        newword = newword + letter
    else:
        print(newword)
        if newword[0].lower()>='h':
            print(newword.upper())
            newword=""
        else:
            newword=""
if newword[0].lower()>='h':
    print(newword.upper())
```

this is a typical edge condition check. Your code rely on new letter to determine current word should be print out or not. "Heart" is the last word and it should be checked at the end of for loop.